# How to display second edit form with current value in the form using django class based view

Tags: django

I have two forms as shown below

```
 class TicketView(ObjectEditView):  
        form_class = forms.FirstForm
        form_class2 = forms.SecondForm
        model = First

        def get(self, request, pk):
            first = get_object_or_404(First, pk = pk)
            return render(request, 'my_folder/file.html', {
                'first': first,
                'form': self.form_class,
                "form2":self.form_class2
            })
```

For the second form there is a drop down,with status as open, close and hold.
I am getting the drop down well using the below code

```
 {% render_field form2.status %}
```

but it's not displaying  current value as selected.

Is there anyway to assign current value of the drop down to the template and then set that value as selected in the drop down using the  render_field?

Something like

```
{% render_field form2.status  value='close' %}
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you meant before. Here is a suggestion what you could do: use `{% render_field form2.status %}` in a `<div class="theDiv" style="display:none;>"` then get the value with JS/jQuery like `$(".theDiv").val...` and set the Dropdown open/close via JS based on true/false status. If you need a detailed answer I can write one, but you could try to find a way yourself with this  guideline :)

Comment: so did that work?